# SVG stroke changes colour when overlaid

Tags: svg

I have a board where I highlight a square using the following:

```
   <g id="marker1" transform="translate(1.5000, 1.500000)" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0.2" >
            <rect  width="37" height="37"
        stroke="yellow" stroke-width="3" stroke-opacity="1"  />
   </g>
```

But the stroke highlight seems to change colour depending on if it is over a dark square or a light square. It is as though the opacity of the stroke is not 100%.

How do I ensure that is doesn't change colour, regardless of which square it is over?

[image: Two different colours]

Comment: From what you've posted, the stroke colours should be the same.  Are you sure it's not an optical illusion?  Otherwise, please post a [mcve] so we can see for ourselves.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Exactly. Same border color may look different with various backgrounds.

Comment: I've updated the original post to show the two different colours, so you can see it is not an optical illusion.

Comment: I've found the solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that in a css file there is an entry referring to the highlighter, and in there it has opacity of 0.5. I changed it to 1 and all is good.